# Const keyword in template argument

Tags: c++, templates, constants, virtual-functions

I have the following C++ code:

```
template<typename T> class AbsClass{
public:
    virtual void func(const T elem) = 0;
};

class SolidClass : public AbsClass<char*>{
public:
    void func(const char* elem) {cout << elem << endl;}
};

int main(){
    SolidClass so;
    so.func("xyz");
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate an instance of SolidClass in main(), the compiler (g++ 4.8.1) keeps complaining the error that the pure virtual function `AbsClass::func(const T elem)` has not been implemented. It would work if I change the definition of SolidClass to the following:

```
class SolidClass : public AbsClass<const char*>{
    .......
}
```

I'm just confused since I already have the `const` keyword in declaring `AbsClass::func(const T elem)`. Could anybody help explain the fact?

Comment: Note: If your compiler supports C++11 then you can write `void func(const char *elem) override {`...   The `override` token says that this function is meant to override a virtual function in a base class, and the compiler will flag an error if it does not (as it does not in this case: it is actually an overload, although you intended to override).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers have two types of const. The first is whether you can modify the data they point to - this const means more of "read-only". The second const is whether the pointer itself is a constant value - that is whether you can make it point to something else. In this case, your pointer `const char*` can be changed to point to something else.

To make a pointer constant (so it cannot point to anything else) you must place a const after the *. So to get it to compile, your code should be:

`void func(const char *const elem)`

Assuming you still want the data it points to, to be read-only through this pointer. You will need to change the template parameter to `AbsClass<const char*>`

If the parameter is by value, I usually avoid making it a const. There is no point, as it is copied anyway, so any local changes by the function don't matter.

Comment: SolidClass is still abstract with this definition.

Comment: @Pradhan That's true!

Comment: @Pradhan @Neil I meant the `const char*`, i.e., the contents cannot be changed rather than the pointer itself. Is there any explanation why SolidClass is abstract?

Comment: @user3791869 Because the parameters need to match in the function. `const char *` is not a constant as required by `const T`

Comment: Top level const is not part of the function signature. In `(const T elem)` , and the second one in `const char *const elem`, it makes no difference to this issue whether that `const` is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `const T` == `T const` and it'll be easier to see that syntactic substitution doesn't yield the same result here. In this case subtituting `char *` in as `T` syntactically causes confusion since it may seem that `const T` is `const char *` and `T const` is `char *const`. In reality both `const T` and `T const` yields `char *const`.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::add_const_t<char *>, char *const>::value, "");
```

Comment: You might clarify that in reality, both `const T` and `T const` are `char * const`.

Answer (score 0):

`const char*` is a pointer to a `const char`. You meant to say `char * const`.

Comment: Not necessarily. He may have meant `const char *const`

Comment: @NeilKirk I was talking about the definition that defines the pure virtual `func`.

Comment: @NeilKirk top level const is not part of the function signature